# How to to select the SIM card for 3g service on a dual SIM?

Tags: android

Normally, to switch internet between SIM cards I do 2 things: choose a SIM card in "Data conn." dialog and then do the same in "Enable 3G" dialog.

I want an app to quickly do both things, but I couldn't find such on Play. There's an example for a uni-SIM phone: http://life-optimized.blogspot.ru/2012/02/android-enabledisable-3g.html . It shows the usage of the method `setMobileDataEnabled(Boolean)`. There should be a similar method for what I need.

I hope it's not a spicific `Zopo` stuff, but even if so, Is there a way to debug the settings menu to see what API is called?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dual SIM cards is not natively supported by Android. This is done possible by modifications that the hardware manufacturer does.